# WAMPServer 3 Change WWW Folder

Tags: php, apache, wampserver

I've just upgrade my WampServer to version 3. I already remove the old version before installing new version. I can successfully change the default www path and also mysql. by changing httpd.conf in the following lines:

```
DocumentRoot "H:/webserver/www/" and `<Directory "H:/webserver/www/">`
```

but when i open localhost host on my browser, it show the following error:

```
(!) Notice: Undefined index: doca in H:\webserver\www\index.php on line 570    Call Stack
```

this is the code on index.php line 570:

```
 <dd>${apacheVersion}&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;<a href='http://{$langues[$langue][$doca_version]}'>Documentation</a></dd>
```

how can I resolve this error? will it affect any other functions/scripts Thanks

Comment: I'm unable to see the index `doca` in the sample code you posted. Can you please check again.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I get the code from index.php when i type localhost in browser. I don't know exactly where it comes from. but the error shows it comes from line 570. I'm unable to resolve the error from my other computer too which has fresh installation. but when i use C:\wamp64\www\index.php it has no such problem.